# 'About This Website' Label on Facebook Posts

Tags: html, facebook, subdomain, blogger, blogs

Is there a way to change the information contained in the 'About This Website' box that appears when you share a link on Facebook?

As my blog is hosted by Blogger, whenever I share a post on Facebook, Blogger's generic info appears, and I would like to change the info to match by site.

[image]

Thanks. :)

Comment: No website can edit this info itself, that would defeat the purpose. If you are using a blogger.com URL to host your blog, switching to your own unique domain would be the first step in getting what Facebook shows changed; however I would expect that it probably doesn’t show any info at all for “small” sites.

Comment: Ah,that's a pity. Where does Facebook get the info for each website, is it purely from WHOIS?

Comment: No, of course not - prose like that (“Blogger is a blog-publishing service that …”) isn’t part of WHOIS data. And it says “From Wikipedia” right there …